# Can't extract the result as expected when using requests_html

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyquery, python-requests-html

I can't extract the correct result with using requests_html:

```
>>> from requests_html import HTMLSession
>>> session = HTMLSession()
>>> r = session.get('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07569DYGN')
>>> r.html.find("#productDetails_detailBullets_sections1")
[]
```

I can find the `id` 'productDetails_detailBullets_sections1' in the source content:

```
>>> """<table id="productDetails_detailBullets_sections1" class="a-keyvalue prodDetTable" role="presentation">""" in r.text
True
```

Actually, the issue similarly exist in PyQuery.

Why can't `requests_html` find this element?

Comment: I can confirm that the source contains `<table id="productDetails_detailBullets_sections1" ...` while the `.find` returns an empty array.

Comment: `r.html.find('table')` doesn't find that object either, seems like `PQuery()` is unhappy about something here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes,it only extracts four tables.

Comment: The PQuery library just translates the CSS selector to the `"descendant-or-self::*[@id = 'productDetails_detailBullets_sections1']` XPath expression, which is valid. So this is down to lxml now; `r.html.pq[0].xpath("descendant-or-self::table")` indeed only returns 4 elements.

Comment: The closest parent that still exists is `r.html.find('#dp-container')`, and it is empty. That's probably where the problem started.

Comment: Possibly because there are two nested divs with the same id. `#product-details-grid_feature_div`. The html is quite a mess.

Comment: @HåkenLid: yup, so "broken html" again, and the parser rightly decided to drop this part.

Comment: @HåkenLid: ah, PyQuery uses the standard lxml etree parser, not the specialist HTML parser. That will make a difference too.

Comment: `PyQuery(r.html.html, parser='html5')('#productDetails_detailBullets_sections1')` finds the element.

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for `#comparison_price_row` which still finds something. The next id in the source is `comparison_shipping_info_row` but searching for `#comparison_shipping_info_row` returns an empty array. The two elements are on the same level (same parent). I examined all the source between the two but found no problem.

At first.

Then I saw that there is a NUL byte somewhere between the two which probably makes the library stumble.

After removing the NUL bytes from the input, the wanted element could be found:

```
r2 = requests_html.HTML(html=r.text.replace('\0', ''))
r2.find('#productDetails_detailBullets_sections1')

[<Element 'table' role='presentation' class=('a-keyvalue', 'prodDetTable') id='productDetails_detailBullets_sections1'>]
```

Comment: Good find. If I read the spec correctly, null characters in a html document should cause a parse error. https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#rcdata-state. So the bug is with amazon, not the lxml parser.

Comment: Yeah, well, we all know how high the rate of errors in typical HTML is today ;-)  So the question always is: How good is the parser in figuring out what was meant despite of the errors.  Ignoring NUL bytes is one of the easier tasks, I guess.

Comment: @Alfe Nice work,but this can't solve the problem from base, only work for this one, dose it? :(
Thank you for your great job.

Comment: @ZhaoyangXu The problem has two aspects:  ① The server is returning HTML with a NUL (which it shouldn't) and ② the parser aborts at the NUL (which is annoying only because of ①).  The main thing is understanding what's happening so one can anticipate similar problems and their symptoms better.  The other thing is to fix the concrete problem at hand.  It doesn't solve all similar issues (like otherwise broken HTML or similar) of course, but at least exactly this one.